# Getting Variable is not defined error, though it is defined. Using EJS & NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, crash, ejs

```
    38|         <h2 class="card-activity">
    39|           <!-- Show Activity -->
 >> 40|           <%= data.activity %>
    41|         </h2>
    42|         <div class="card-info">
    43|           <span class="card-type">

data is not defined
```

On refreshing and retrying multiple times, it gets solved, but why am I facing this error ?

index.js:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://bored-api.appbrewery.com/random");
    const result = response.data;
    res.render("index.ejs", { data: result });
    //res.locals = {data: {}}
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to make request:", error.message);
    res.render("index.ejs", {
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
});
```

index.ejs:

```
<div class="card-info">
          <span class="card-type">
            <!-- Show Activity type -->
            <%= data.type %>
          </span>
          <span class="card-participants">
            <!-- participants: Show participant number -->
            <%= data.participants %>
            <span class="card-number"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
```

On refreshing and retrying multiple times, it gets solved, but why am I facing this error ?
Please suggest what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

> but why am I facing this error ?

Because `data` is not defined.  Note that you *sometimes* define it for the view:

```
res.render("index.ejs", { data: result });
```

And *sometimes* don't:

```
res.render("index.ejs", {
  error: error.message,
});
```

The difference between the two is whether or not an exception occurred.  So the described behavior suggests that an exception occurred.

Since `data` only ever conditionally exists, the view can't assume it will exist.  You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to gracefully handle when it doesn't exist:

```
<h2 class="card-activity">
  <!-- Show Activity -->
  <%= data?.activity %>
</h2>
```

Or perhaps only render entire sections of the view if it exists:

```
<% if(data){ %>
  <!-- All of the view that uses data goes here -->
<% } %>
```

(As for what you do with the `error` value, that's up to you.)

Comment: Just to add the `https://bored-api.appbrewery.com/random` API will return a `429 Too Many Requests` error if it's being spammed which I assume multiple fetch requests by OP is what causes the fetch to throw an error and subsequently causes `data not defined` error thanks to the `res.render` in the `catch`.